# How to populate a PostgresQL column with a list of all values from column1 from all rows with the current row’s value of column2

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

I have a Postgres table with the following format:

| Fruit | Owner |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | John |
| Orange | Susan |
| Pear | Michael |
| Peach | Susan |

I want to write a query that creates a new column, `Owner's Fruits`, which lists all fruits owned by the owner of the row in question, like this:

| Fruit | Owner | Owner's Fruits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | John | Apple |
| Orange | Susan | Orange, Peach |
| Pear | Michael | Pear |
| Peach | Susan | Orange, Peach |

However, I am unable to figure out how to do this, nor even how to phrase my question so that I find an answer on here or Google.

It seems like it should be simple enough. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `string_agg()`:

```
select t.*,
       string_agg(fruit, ',') over (partition by owner) as owners_fruits
from t;
```

That said, I actually recommend putting the values into an array instead:

```
select t.*,
       array_agg(fruit) over (partition by owner) as owners_fruits
from t;
```

Arrays are more versatile.

Comment: Perfect! That does it. Thank you!